# Mimikatz infinite loop

Tags: windows, powershell, infinite-loop

When I'm trying to run mimikatz in powershell, it goes into an infinite loop everytime. I searched a lot but I couldn't find a solution.

```
PS C:\Temp> .\mimikatz.exe

  .#####.   mimikatz 2.2.0 (x64) #18362 Jan  4 2020 18:59:26
 .## ^ ##.  "A La Vie, A L'Amour" - (oe.eo)
 ## / \ ##  /*** Benjamin DELPY `gentilkiwi` ( benjamin@gentilkiwi.com )
 ## \ / ##       > http://blog.gentilkiwi.com/mimikatz
 '## v ##'       Vincent LE TOUX             ( vincent.letoux@gmail.com )
  '#####'        > http://pingcastle.com / http://mysmartlogon.com   ***/

mimikatz #
mimikatz #
mimikatz #
mimikatz #
mimikatz #
mimikatz #
mimikatz #
<--------- Continues like this ---------->
```

Comment: Why!? Also, why look at this as a PowerShell specific issue, vs. mimikatz functional issue surfaced in the consolehost. What happens when you pass it a command vs just the interactive request? You are also not giving the full story, meaning, what OS versions and PSVerison are you doing this with, what profile, user-level (std/admin).

Comment: i have same problem during loading a mimikatz.exe copy on Wreath Lab on TryHackMe. Still understanding why